# Cocoa: Localize Dialog

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm currently translating my application (Mac OS X app) into another language. I've done almost all translations, but now I'm stuck on a pretty strange thing:

I have an additional window for the applications settings and translated the GUI elements the same way I did it for the main window. I imported the translations into my project which seemed to work fine because I can use the preview windows, switch the language of the assistant editor to German and see that the dialog will be localized correctly.

But as soon as I run my application (with "German" as language) and open the settings dialog the whole dialog is still in English (the base language).

The settings dialog's XIB file is located in the base.lproj folder and the corresponding .strings file is located in the de.lproj folder (which should be correct as the preview shows the correct translations).
I don't know what's going on and have no clue what might be the issue.

Does someone have any clue?
I'm using Xcode 6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for this issue: Localizing the settings dialog forced Xcode to move it into the Base.lproj folder. But instead of moving the file Xcode just copied it into that folder - so the XIB file for the dialog existed twice and Cocoa used the old one (which was not localized).

After cleaning the build directory and deleting the derived data for the project the localization works fine now.

Comment: It's what usually happens if you have an old build hanging around - Xcode won't automatically delete old files, just add the new ones.  A clean build is the way to go.